# Custom Overlay Of Camera Controls and how to apply actions in iOS

Tags: cordova, ios-camera

I am Using an Custom overlay for Developing a Camera application on iOS using cordova 3.0

inside the take picture function i am trying to keep custom button's for camera , gallery and flip 
so when i am applying actions to the buttons its not Executing the actions .

```
 UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shoot" style:(UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered) target:self action:@selector(takepic:)];

-(void)takepic:(..)command
 {
  }
```

so how to apply action for the above button . how to assign camera capture for the above button.

Comment: Found some answer in here For this :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440665/uiimagepickercontroller-takepicture-issues)